# want to use panda to make it look/work like sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pysqlite

```
    pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
    str1 = "select coalesce(ID1, H_ID, [Alternate Source Unique 
    Identifier]) as Master_ID, [Alternate Source Unique Identifier] as Q_ID 
    from crosswalk;"
     with Timer("Load master_ids:"):
    master_id_list = pysql(str1)
    print("Records: {}".format(len(master_id_list)))
    master_id_list.head()
```

pySQL runs in just 5 seconds !!

I want to write the second script in python because I can't use pysql :(, Any idea ? your best translation of the second script in python please ?

I have done 2 propositions but not really effective in term of time
The first one without Pandas (which is the required)

```
    def coalesce (df, column_names):
    i=iter(column_names)
    column_name=next(i)
    answer=df[colum_name]
    for column_name in i:
    answer = answer.fillna(df[column_name])
    return answer
    coalesce(df, ['first', 'third', 'second'])
```

Thank you for your advices !

Comment: why are you using the ``copy()`` method? I think It creates a lot of overhead.

Comment: Thank you, what do you suggest instead of copy ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to count the number of records (`len(master_id_list)`) you can just use it directly:

`crosswalk['ID'].size`

or

`crosswalk.shape`

if you are looking for unique values, try:

`crosswalk['ID'].unique().size`

Comment: Thank you      Ok for this , but I need to reformulante the first script using the idea in script 2 ... does this make sens ?

Comment: I might be missing something - don't you just print the number of the results?

Comment: I just want to use panda and make it look like sql ... also in term of performances